# git push failed. fatal: does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I have looked over at least 30 search results for this error message and none of them have been the same issue that I am having. I have an existing project that has git commits and zero remotes. I want to create a remote for this repository on a shared network drive at the office so that others will have access. I have done this with mercurial many times without issue so expected it to be a simple matter with git. I was also able to send multiple projects to bitbucket using similar commands to the ones listed below so I am puzzled why I am having difficulty doing it locally.
Additionally, I was unable to perform this task with SourceTree which was also producing the same errors.

The steps I have taken are as follows:

```
$ cd R:/TestDirectory
$ git init --bare test.git

$ cd C:/Dev/SampleProject
$ git remote add origin R:/TestDirectory/test.git //(with and without the test.git at the end)
$ git push -u origin --all
fatal: R:/TestDirectory/test.git does not appear to be a git repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm a blockhead, but apparently I overlooked cloning first. I think I was also having issues because my git terminal uses forwarded slashes and some others I have seen use backslashes. The step I was missing was to

```
git clone ./ driveLetter:/destinationFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you are trying to do but `R:/TestDirectory/test.git` can never be a Git repository however if you have git installed and a repository is initialized that way

`http://127.0.0.1/test.git` 
can be a repository

Comment: Not even using the file protocol: `file://R:/path/here.git`? Not sure about the drive letter but a path works fine under Linux.

Comment: @musiKk Not sure about that havent used it but i beleive not the way he was doing it.